# How can I show last 10 indexes in Highcharts Timeline and left using scroll?

Tags: highcharts

I have data like this:

```
var data = [{
    x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
    name: 'First dogs in space',
    label: 'fds',
    dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: false,
        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
            '</span><br/>{point.label}'
    },
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite',
    label: 'First artificial satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
    name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
    label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
    name: 'First human spaceflight',
    label: 'First human spaceflight',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
    name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
    label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
    name: 'First human on the Moon',
    label: 'First human on the Moon',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19),
    name: 'First space station',
    label: 'First space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
    name: 'First soft Mars landing',
    label: 'First soft Mars landing',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
    name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
    label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1978, 11, 4),
    name: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
    label: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1986, 1, 19),
    name: 'First inhabited space station',
    label: 'First inhabited space station',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
    name: 'First astrometric satellite',
    label: 'First astrometric satellite',
}, {
    x: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
    name: 'First multinational space station',
    label: 'First multinational space station',
}];
```

Fiddle For refrence:
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vd9efr8a/)

In this, I want to show the last 10 indexes Timeline and left indexes I can access through scrolling back.
And also I want when I click on any label div size is changed to random size So I want it's redraw() the chart and adjust according to div size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have static values you can make sure the 10 last indexes are shown by setting them as `min` and `max` for the x-axis. You could calculate this before setting up the chart options if you know the data. In your case ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cque6z27/)):

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    min: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
    max: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
    visible: false,
},
```

If it is dynamic you can do it in postprocessing of the chart by finding the `min` and `max` for the axis by looking at the points of your series. For example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cque6z27/1/)):

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    // ...
}, function() {
    const min = Math.max(this.series[0].points.length - 10, 0);
    const max = Math.max(this.series[0].points.length - 1, 0);
    this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(this.series[0].points[min].x, this.series[0].points[max].x);
});
```

Comment: Thanks it's working fine but there is a problem when I clicked on some label its div size gonna change because of random size is given and some labels are hidden so can you please help me out so all label can adjust in div I tried to redraw() but it's not working.

Comment: I want when I click on some labels it adjusts width size or redraws the chart so that all labels come according to my condition or selected items.

Comment: @vikash I'm not sure I completely understand. If I click on a data label you want ALL data labels to change to a different size? Do you want the chart area to resize as well, since I see you are currently resizing the chart area? I need a better understanding of what (and maybe why) to answer the question. I was [experimenting with this](https://jsfiddle.net/90kwnp24/) while trying to understand.

Comment: Yes, @Halvor I want to resize the chart area after the label clicked but the problem is when I clicked on some label chart area is gonna less than current size and some labels are hidden. So I just want to draw a chart in this area.

Comment: I'm waiting for valuable response Thanks!